# window.focus(), self.focus() not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi all i am developing a chat application ... i have multiple chat windows ... i want to know which windw contain new message ... i have the following code ..

```
function getCount()
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: baseUrl + '/Chat/count',
       data: "chat_id=" + document.ajax.chat_id.value,
       success: function(msg){
                if(msg == 'new1') {
                    self.focus();
                                            //window.focus();

                }
            }
    });
}
```

If an operator attending both chat....

for example the url is like 
http://localhost/nisanth/admin/Chat/index/chatId/15
http://localhost/nisanth/admin/Chat/index/chatId/16

http://localhost/nisanth/user/Chat/index/chatId/15
http://localhost/nisanth/user/Chat/index/chatId/16

if the `user 16` enter a message i need focus

```
http://localhost/nisanth/admin/Chat/index/chatId/16
```

This code is work fine with IE but not in firefox...please give me a solution... the above code is in the same html

Comment: I don't see how that can work in IE; `self` is undefined in the quoted code. If it's defined elsewhere, best to show that since it's kind of important to know what it's meant to reference.

Comment: How does "...i want to know which window contain new message..." relate to `focus` not doing what you expect? (Also, can you explain more what you mean by that?)

Comment: @Nisanth: `window` may be, but again, not `self` unless you're defining it somewhere else. `self` is not a built-in object. It's the name a lot of people use inside a closure they're passing as a callback/event handler when they want to refer to the `this` value from within the closure, but to do that, you have to actually define it (e.g., `var self= this;`).

Comment: self.focus() is working in IE8

Comment: Well whatever, @Nisanth; it's irrelevant to the question of what will work in Firefox, because in Firefox it's under user control.

Comment: @Pointy is there any trick to handle my issue in firefox

Comment: Read my answer, @Nisanth.  You cannot override the user configuration.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Most browsers implement a global variable named `self`, which is simply a reference back to the global object, is not part of any specification but seems that it exist on every browser... (`window.self == window`) https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.self

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firefox will only obey requests to raise a window if a security option is set, and it's not set by default. Chrome won't pay attention to focus() requests at all, as far as I can tell. Safari does obey focus() request.

The specific Firefox setting is in the "Tools" -> "Options" ("Edit -> Preferences" on Linux, maybe MacOS) dialog. There's a "Content" tab, and in that there's a checkbox for enabling Javascript. Along with *that* is an "Advanced" button that brings up *another* dialog, wherein one finds a checkbox to allow (or disallow) the raising and lowering of windows by page code.

**edit:** Here is a test page: http://gutfullofbeer.net/focus1.html and you should be able to see that Firefox *will* raise a window when the page calls `window.focus()`.  You must either have the browser set up so that new windows (created with `window.open()`) open up in a new separate window instead of a tab, or else you can tear off the tab of the secondary page when it opens.

Comment: Well then you must be doing something wrong, because it definitely works. Have you tried issuing an "alert()" when you think that your call to "window.focus()" is taking place?

Comment: alert is working, self.blur(), working, window.moveTo() these all r working :(... if alert() is working then the window is get focused but my client don't want that ;)

Comment: I have used window.focus() in my own applications, and I am 100% certain that it works in Firefox when the browser is configured to allow it.

Comment: your example is working fine here... but i think my case have some issue...:( is there any way to alert window object....

Comment: Uhh ... well, I'm not sure what you mean; the "window" object is built into the browser. Now it's possible that something has *changed* the `focus()` function, but that does not seem very likely.

Comment: Sadly this answer is no longer relevant as the preferences window has changed dramatically and the setting is no longer found in there.

Comment: @ThomasPaine ancient Stackoverflow questions are an interesting problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i though there was a problem with my JS script, after a long search i have found a solution:

1) In a new tab, type **about:config** in the address bar and press button "Enter". Click the button "I accept the risk!" in order to confirm the warning

2) In the search field, type **dom.disable** to get **dom.disable_window_flip**

3) If the property **dom.disable_window_flip** is true, double-click it to switch the value from true to false

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking to focus on a tab, another tab (tab A) can bring a different tab (tab B) to the front.

If the `window.name` of tab B is 'myWindow123', then in tab A run this:

```
window.open('', 'myWindow123');
```

If you want to re-focus on the tab that opened you, run:

```
window.open('', window.opener.name);
```