# How to focus window/tab like alert()?

Tags: javascript

If in some of my tabs alert() is executed, then this tab becomes selected instantly. The thing is - this alert() box is ugly. I have created  with my design and all.. But when I call it - tab is not selected/focused.
window.focus(); does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `window.alert` function? i.e. `window.alert = function(text) {....}` and see if this doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.focus(), self.focus() not working in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533305/window-focus-self-focus-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: window.alert = function(text) {....} works but does not provide window focusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reliably force windows or tabs to grab focus. Some browsers are more amenable to the idea than others: IE will generally allow it, but Firefox has to be configured by the user to allow it, and Safari will basically never honor a focus request. (Well, almost never.)

Comment: Then I'll need to rely on ugly alert() box.

Comment: I have a simple implementation of this working fine in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: @thepeer, Mind showing us or offering a link to a jsfiddle or something? ;)

Comment: I've long since forgotten how I did it, sorry.

Comment: then why bother commenting?

Comment: I don't have verification, but changing the `document.title` value seems to bring a *window* to focus; perhaps it works on tabs as well.

Comment: @rvighne is this for safari ?