# How can i get the newly opened browser tab name from origin tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code like this to create the new tab from one tab to another in same browser.

```
function newTab()
{
    var form1 = document.createElement("form");
    form1.id = "newTab1"
    form1.method = "GET";
    form1.action = "domainname";  //My site address
    form1.target = "framename";   //Browser tab name
    document.body.appendChild(form1);
    form1.submit();
}
```

Above code works correctly to create the new tab . when click from "MyNewTab" link the home page

```
<a href="javascript:newTab()" style=" margin-left:15px;" id="newTab"> MyNewTab </a>
```

Again i try to switch over home page to newly opened tab. This time need to switch from home page to new Tab without reload. But this newtab content reloaded.

How to get the tab name and get focus the newly opened tab from click the "MyNewTab" link ?

Comment: `without reload` reload the home page? Do you want to open a new tab without refresh the home page?

Comment: Every time clicking the link reload the newly opened tab. i don't need of this activity. i need on the second click should focus the already opened tab. Is any possible ?

Comment: It's possible easily.. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set the current selected tab in javascript cookie, and always read this cookie at page load and set the tab

you can set the cookie inside the newTab() function:

```
function newTab()
{
    var form1 = document.createElement("form");
    form1.id = "newTab1"
    form1.method = "GET";
    form1.action = "domainname";  //My site address
    form1.target = "framename";   //Browser tab name

    $.cookie("currentTab", "framename");//set the selected tab name in cookie

    document.body.appendChild(form1);
    form1.submit();
}
```

then, on page load event:

```
var tabName=$.cookie("currentTab")//get the current tab name from cookie.
if(tabName==null){
tabName="default tab name"//at first time the cookie will be null, 
//so you need to assign a default value if the cookie is null
}

//set this tab as selected
```

Comment: I adding these line into my code "$.cookie is not defined error" is occured.

Comment: I need to set the java script cookie for this problem thank you for help

Comment: but you just need to add the jquery reference to  make the above code work

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to use [`window.open()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) and [`window.focus()`](http://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_win_focus.asp).

**Explanation:** When user click on the button you check if the new tab already open. If so, you just use `window.focus()`. If not, you open it using `window.open()`.

Like this:

```js
var new_win;
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
  if (new_win) {
    new_win.focus();
  }
  else {
    new_win = window.open('second_page_url');
  }
};
```

```html
<button>Open tab</button>
```

**Note:** This code not working in the snippet (because the security) so you can see the it in http://jsbin.com/tebecu

Comment: Thank you so much it works fine in chrome browser. But do not work in Other browser like (Firefox). Is Any solution for this?

Comment: I afraid that it's not possible because of security reason on `Firefox`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052388/how-to-get-window-focus-to-work-in-firefox