# Set Window focus with a link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with Javascript window focus setting.
I've written a function to open a new window with the JS method window.open() and save the return value to a variable.
Now I have a link on the first page and by clicking on this link the second, with window.open() opened, window should get the focus.
But this won't work. Is there any way to get this working?

My code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
var myWindow;
function checkForRefresh() {
                myWindow = window.open("test.html", "TestMain");
                myWindow.focus();
}

function switchFocus(umsWindow) {
                myWindow.focus();
}
</script>

</head>

<body onLoad="checkForRefresh()"> 

<p><a href="javascript:switchFocus();">Test Link</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been talked already, some browsers does not listen to `window.focus()`. Please take a look at [comment #2533335](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2533335/1180790).

Comment: Is there any workaround without reconfiguring Firefox?

Comment: Sorry, I don`t know any one at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work when I made the functions properly global by putting them on the `window` object

http://jsfiddle.net/u52xE/3/

```
window.switchFocus = function() {
    myWindow.focus();
}
```

It's not ideal to have that javascript in your HTML and global functions though, I'd recommend using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to attach events

Comment: Hi thanks for this code, but it won't work in FF24. When it opens it gets the focus, but by using the link it won't get the focus.